# best way to handle frequent HTTP POST request from iPad app

Tags: ios, http-request

In my app for iPad, I have a requirement that I have to post some data almost after each 30 sec. So for that I'm creating a new http request every time and adding the request to a queue.

Is there any other efficient way to do so?